# In R, what does the error "need at least one panel" mean and how to fix it?

Tags: r, lattice

The following code is from the book "R in Action", listing 16.1:

```
library(lattice)
attach(mtcars)

gear <- factor(gear, levels=c(3, 4, 5),
               labels=c("3 gears", "4 gears", "5 gears"))
cyl <- factor(cyl, levels=c(4, 6, 8),
              labels=c("4 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "8 cylinders"))

densityplot(~mpg,
            main="Density Plot",
            xlab="Miles per Gallon")

densityplot(~mpg | cyl,
            main="Density Plot by Number of Cylinders",
            xlab="Miles per Gallon")

bwplot(cyl ~ mpg | gear,main="Box Plots by Cylinders and Gears",
       xlab="Miles per Gallon", ylab="Cylinders")


xyplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl * gear,
       main="Scatter Plots by Cylinders and Gears",
       xlab="Car Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon")

cloud(mpg ~ wt * qsec | cyl,
      main="3D Scatter Plots by Cylinders")

dotplot(cyl ~ mpg | gear,
        main="Dot Plots by Number of Gears and Cylinders",
        xlab="Miles Per Gallon")

splom(mtcars[c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)],
      main="Scatter Plot Matrix for mtcars Data")

detach(mtcars)
```

I am able to plot only the first density plot and the last plot, splom(...). The rest of the plots give me the following error:

> Error in limits.and.aspect(default.prepanel, prepanel = prepanel, have.xlim = have.xlim,  : 
>     need at least one panel

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

I have just started learning R and the version I am using is:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Malaysia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Malaysia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Malaysia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=English_Malaysia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-29

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0
```

EDIT:

Output of search() is:

```
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "mtcars"            "package:lattice"  
 [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
 [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran those exactly? They work for me. Maybe restart your R session and try again. The examples do show the bad practice of attaching a data.frame to the search path rather than just including it as a parameter to the plotting function so i'm not sure that's a great set to learn from. Also, the output of `sessionInfo()` would be more useful than the version information.

Comment: What if you try `densityplot(~mpg | cyl, mtcars, main="Density Plot by Number of Cylinders", xlab="Miles per Gallon")` instead. Does that work? Forget about attaching the data.frame.

Comment: @MrFlick yes, I ran those exactly. To be sure, I closed R, opened it, copied the above code into a new script, selected all the code and ran it with Ctrl+R. The errors still appear

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, your suggestion to include the dataframe into the graphing function works! Any idea what it causing this weird behaviour and what does the error mean anyway?

Comment: When you type `mtcars`, do you see the data? What does your search path look like, `search()`? Did the `attach` command run without errors? Do you have the `datasets` package attached as well? I'm guessing the error is due to the fact that the function can't find the conditioning variables (those after the "|").

Comment: @MrFlick yes, I can see the data when I type mtcars and mtcars is included in search(). I just realised that this is hard to reproduce as it happened on a few occasions that I am able to run the code as is but subsequently not. By the way, how do you make the words appear with a gray background in the comments?

Comment: When it happens there must be some problem resolving the variable names. I can't think of any reason that should happen. You could type each of the variable names in the formula to make sure the values are found. But I would strongly discourage you from using the `attach()` method anyway, and pass the data.frame explicitly to the plotting function. You can get the inline code in comments if you surround the code with back-ticks (the button to the left of "1" on top of the keyboard).

Comment: this is also my problem. do you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I copy the code from [QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html). 
I solved it by changing the levels of gear and cyl from int to string since the values in the dataset are all strings.

```
gear.f<-factor(gear,levels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears"),
    labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
cyl.f <-factor(cyl,levels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"),
    labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the data `"mtcars"` as below,

```
bwplot(cyl ~ mpg | mtcars$gear, main = "Box Plots by Cylinders and Gears", xlab = "Miles per Gallon", ylab = "Cylinders")
```

it works for me.